# Java: Prepare a statement without a connection

Tags: java, sql

I'm trying to generate some sql files in my java application.
The application will **not** execute any sql statements, just generate a file with sql statements and save it.

I'd like to use the `java.sql.PreparedStatement` to create my statements so that i don't have to validate every string etc. with my own methods.

Is there a way to use the `PreparedStatement` without the calling `java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(String)` function, because I don't have a `java.sql.Connection`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this Java library: http://openhms.sourceforge.net/sqlbuilder/

Comment: This library imports the package "com.healthmarketscience.common.util" which isn't included...

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that until you've got a sql connection, the parser won't know what rules to apply.  I'm guessing that it's actually the SQL driver or even server that's compiling the sql statement.

Assuming your sql is simple enough, then how about using a cheap connection, like, say a sqlite connection.

SQLite will create a new database on the fly if the database you're attempting to connect to does not exist.

```
public Connection connectToDatabase() {

// connect to the database (creates new if not found)
try {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:mydatabase.db");

    // initialise the tables if necessary
    this.createDatabase(conn);
}
catch (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}

return conn;

}
```

Comment: So, how can I create a connection without something to connect to?

Comment: sqlite will create a new database for you if it doesn't exist - added a proof of concept code snippet

Comment: Update, just learned that SQLite databases can be created in memory only with connection string "jdbc:sqlite::memory:"

Answer (score 1):

Not really. Preparing a statement in most cases means that it will be compiled by DBMS which is "hard" without connection.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: If it wasn't hard he wouldn't be asking ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is a dastardly devious problem, thankfully it's pretty easy to cope with:

```
public class PreparedStatementBuilder
{
    private String sql; // the sql to be executed

    public PreparedStatementBuilder(final String sql) { this.sql = sql; }

    protected void preparePrepared(final PreparedStatement preparedStatement) 
            throws SQLException 
    {
        // this virtual method lets us declare how, when we do generate our
        // PreparedStatement, we want it to be setup.

        // note that at the time this method is overridden, the 
        // PreparedStatement has not yet been created.
    }

    public PreparedStatement build(final Connection conn)
            throws SQLException
    {
        // fetch the PreparedStatement
        final PreparedStatement returnable = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        // perform our setup directives
        preparePrepared(returnable);
        return returnable;
    }
}
```

To use, just write an anonymous class that overrides void preparePrepared(PreparedStatement):

```
    final String sql = "SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE USER = ?";
    PreparedStatementBuilder psBuilder = new PreparedStatementBuilder(sql){
        @Override
        protected void preparePrepared(PreparedStatement preparedStatement)
            throws SQLException
        {
            preparedStatement.setString(1, "randal");
        }};
    return obtainResultSet(psBuilder);
```

Presto! You now have a way to work with a PreparedStatement without yet having built it. Here's an example showing the minimal boilerplate you'd otherwise have to copy paste to kingdom come, every time you wanted to write a different statement:

```
public ResultSet obtainResultSet(final PreparedStatementBuilder builder)
        throws SQLException {
    final Connection conn = this.connectionSource.getConnection();
    try
    {
        // your "virtual" preparePrepared is called here, doing the work 
        // you've laid out for your PreparedStatement now that it's time 
        // to actually build it.
        return builder.build(conn).executeQuery();
    }
    finally
    {
        try { conn.close(); } 
        catch (SQLException e) { log.error("f7u12!", e); }
    }
}
```

You really really don't want to be copy pasting that everywhere, do you?

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing PreparedStatement.

Example : class YourOwnClass implements PreparedStatement {

// 1. Do implement all the methods ,
   2. Get the minimal logic to implement from  OraclePreparedStatement(classes12.jar) or 
 sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcCallableStatement

}

Comment: @r3zn1k: The advantage of implementing this is that the code is then re-usable: it can either generate text SQL or directly execute the SQL.  However I wouldn't be surprised if you didn't need that flexibility. :)